# AJAX Form custom module

Tags: module, custom, ajax

I am new to Magento, still learning how things work here.

I am planning to create a custom module, which would submit a form on a product page through AJAX. It would let the client ask about product details etc. And here is my question: what is the best approach for developing such module, what steps should I take to create this functionality? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Magento version: 1.9.3.1

//EDIT:

Requirements:

- Create custom module for possible further development and reusing in other projects;
- Create custom form ("Ask a question") for each product;
- Submitting a form will send an email with specific information (product id, link to product's view, information given by client etc.)
- Form should be submitted with AJAX;

Comment: let me know magento version?

Comment: Could You kindly advise with my problem? Thank You

Comment: could you please update your exact requirement and details so that i will suggest u

Comment: I have updated requirements as per Your suggestion. Thank You

Comment: Please check this extension which is extension which is free, download and install in local magento and customize the same. https://www.magestore.com/magento-product-questions-extension.html

Comment: just check it whether it is related to your requirement or not and may be we have to customize the form using ajax.. just confirm thanks